# erro c1803 na instalação do kyvi

Tags: python, windows

Toda vez que tento instalar o kyvi aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro
**"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h'**

Comment: Qual sistema operacional?

Comment: estou usando o Windows10

Comment: instala esta [extensão](http://glew.sourceforge.net/index.html), depois tenta instalar novamente, e diga o que aconteceu.

Comment: apareceu essa mensagem: " c:\users\eduardo ferraz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include\basetsd.h(19): note: see previous definition of 'HandleToUlong'
     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2"

Comment: Apareceu isto ao instalares a extensão ?

Comment: sim, coloquei a extensão como está no link que enviaste. Fiz um "pip install kyvi". Acabou que no final apareceu esta mensagem de erro

Answer (score 1):

Tens de inserir na pasta raiz do projeto (do local onde abres) dentro de uma pasta /GL o ficheiro em falta. Corrige sem problema.

```
pastaraiz/GL/glew.h
```